# What are the definitions of arithmetic genus and geometric genus over a field of characteristic $p$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, algebraic-curves

Let $k$ be a field with characteristic $p$. Let $C$ be a projective curve over $k$, which may be disconnected or singular.

What are the (universal?) definitions of the arithmetic genus and the geometric genus of $C$?

Comment: Did you do any searching on your own? Stacks answers both of these questions: [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BY6) for arithmetic genus, and [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BYE) for geometric genus.

Comment: @KReiser Yes. But I’m not sure about the definitions when 1) the base field has positive characteristic, 2) the curve is singular (also not necessarily connected). I’m also not sure if they are universal definitions; in other words, are there (non-equivalent) different definitions people may use?

Comment: Both definitions make no restriction on $k$ other than it being a field, which means they apply just fine to curves over fields of positive characteristic (satisfying the $H^0=k$ assumption - I've never seen genus defined for disconnected curves). The definition of arithmetic genus makes no reference to smoothness and thus applies to both smooth and nonsmooth curves. The linked definition of geometric genus explains how to apply it to a nonsmooth curve. Inequivalent defintions would be rare (except for the comment in the arithmetic genus post about the base field) and I have not seen any.

Comment: @KReiser For arithmetic genus, my only doubt is whether there is a universal definition for disconnected curve. For example, the arithmetic genus for a disjoint union of two lines is minus one. For geometric genus, things are clear now (if we trust the stacks project as a universal truth).